# flutter shared_preferences shared over all devices of user using drive/icloud or NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore for Android

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sharedpreferences, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I'm wondering if there is any way to allow the user to backup the shared_preferences to drive or icloud?

I save some data from a questionnaire to shared preferences. These data are effecting the content that is available for the user.

Target: If the user installs the app on a new device these shared preferences should be restored from his cloud backup automaticly or as a given option.

on iOS there is NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore to achieve this but is there an equivalent for Android?